# Which is faster? $n^{\log n}$ or $(\log n)^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

Which is faster? $n^{\log n}$ or $(\log n)^n$?

Should I look at the base or at the exponent when I'm confronting two exponential functions?

Comment: Hint: write both as $e^\text{something}$.

Comment: @Wojowu in this case $n^{logn}$ is faster but I checked their graphics and $n^{logn}$ seems to be slower

Comment: @user649882 [Really](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DiscretePlot%5B+%7Bn%5E(Log%5Bn%5D),+Log%5Bn%5D%5En%7D,+%7Bn,1,20%7D+%5D)? $n^{\log n} = 2^{\log^2 n}$, how would it be "faster" than $(\log n)^n = 2^{n\log n}$?

Comment: $\overbrace{\ \ \frac{\log(n)^2}{n}\ \ }^{\frac1n\log\left(\color{#C00}{n^{\log(n)}}\right)}\to0$ and $\overbrace{\log(\log(n))\vphantom{\frac{(n)^2}n}}^{\frac1n\log\left(\color{#C00}{\log(n)^n}\right)}\to\infty$, so it would seem that $\log(n)^n$ grows faster.

Comment: @ClementC. to see which function is the fastest between two on a graphic like on desmos.com/calculator you have to see which function is closer to the y axis as it grows, am I wrong?

Comment: You just have to look at which one is "above" the other. Or you could plot the ratio and see if it's going above or below 1.

Comment: @ClementC. what do you mean by "above"?

Comment: Notice that $ \log(n^{\log n}) = (\log n)^2$ grows slower than any polynomials, while $\log((\log n)^n)=n\log\log n$ grows faster than any linear polynomials. So, in terms of the original functions, $n^{\log n}$ grows slower than any exponential functions while $(\log n)^n$ grow faster than any exponential functions. I hope this is clear enough to tell which one grows after.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a standard exponential:
$$n^{\log n}=\mathrm e^{\log^2n}, \quad (\log n)^n=\mathrm e^{n\log(log n)}$$
then check whether $\;\log^2n=o\bigl(n\log(\log n)\bigr)\:$ or $\;n\log(\log n)=o\bigl(\log^2n\bigr)$.

Comment: is $n^n$ faster than $n^{logn}$?

Comment: @user649882, Yes, because the exponent of $n^n$ is much larger than that of $n^{\log n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n} \le \frac{n}{\ln n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

If $2\le a < b$, then $b^a < a^b$. So $n^{\log n} < (\log n)^n$ for all $n>7$.

(This bound isn't tight--it's actually true for all $n > 5$. But it should still be good enough.)